# Find a Basis of ker(T) and a Basis of im(T) for a Linear Transformation of a Matrix to a Polynomial

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathcal{M}_{2\times2} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_{2}$ be the linear map such that $T\left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{bmatrix}\right) = \mathrm{trace}(A)x^{2} + c(x-1) + b$. Find a basis of $\ker(T)$ and im$(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Trace$(A)=a+d$, so $T(A)=(a+d)x^2+cx+(b-c)$. For the kernel, you want those matrices $A$ such that $T(A)=0$. So, we want $(a+d)x^2+cx+(b-c)$ to be the zero polynomial. This means
$$a+d=0, \qquad c=0, \qquad b-c=0.$$
Thus
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&-a\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
So a basis for the kernel is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Now try a similar approach for the image and see which polynomials can be mapped to using $T$. A better question to ask, can we map to each of the following polynomials or not $1,x,x^2$?